# Routing by back end (nodeJs) or front end (angularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ejs, template-engine

today I have a very important question to ask from people experience in javascript and their respected frameworks.

I am creating an application in nodeJs and have defined **routes** in **backend**.
For every **html** to display on client side I made route on back end with help of template engine **ejs**.

I can also make routes on front end too with help of ng-route and display the html page according to the defined routes. But it is not possible if you made routes on back end.

My front end code is inside the back end code in specified folder and template engine can access that folder (custom js) for viewing in html.

Some people said that you should make route on front end because same html page  rendered on server side and you are sending it again to view side to render.

Is there anyone who can explain me the process effectively and which process is better ?

Motivation of application is to read the apis from back end and render the view in tabular form.

Comment: If you're making a SPA (Single Page Application), you will want your backend to serve your index.html to all non-api routes, and allow your client side code to handle the internal routing of the SPA.

Comment: @mscdex I'm trying to find the value of your edit, outside of getting yourself reputation points.

Comment: @KyleRichardson It's just that if you are placing your client side code in back end code base , it will not render html. 
1) Either you go to template engine 
2) Or you go to make dynamic routes on front end side.
And is it right same html page rendered on server side and you are sending it again to view side to render.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but you can definitely have your backend code render a default view that your client side code will then modify according to route.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Thanks for your participation but not worked for me

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to help. Best of luck to you sir!

Comment: @KyleRichardson Because StackOverflow is searchable from google and thus having correct spelling will help find such questions better? That's the main reason for any/all spelling corrections I make to questions (provided it is not changing code or similar important things that should remain intact for obvious reasons).

Comment: @mscdex odd, the edit shows the same before and after for me, I truly apologize in this case.